# Как вывести содержимое файла? Выводит только URL до файла, но не содержимое

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

```
<? file_get_contents('files/inc/'.the_field('filename')); ?>
```

the_field команда плагина acf, где хранится имя файла.

Не получается не file_get_contents, не php include...
Можно пример, как это сделать?

Все что пробовал **выводит только URL до файла**, а не его содержимое...

Comment: This is __russian__ stackoverflow. People speak russian here.

Comment: Сорри, поправил!

Comment: Это ВП и тут подключать через file_get_contents не правильно. Но ты уже принял неправильной ответ. А тепрь когда возникнут траблы - приходи и спроси как сделать правильно, а не про синтаксис php-функции.

Comment: Вообще запутался, а как правильно? Снял "правильный ответ"

Comment: Создай новый вопрос, не предлагая в нём же решений (функций php). Опиши что откуда, зачем (какой результат нужно получить) и  куда именно нужно вставить содержимое файла. (И вообще зачем файла.. Боюсь что и тут ты не правильно решил хотелку). И не ставь метки `php`. А снял принятый ответ напрасно - ты спросил про php-функцию -  человек тебе и ответил про неё.

Answer (score 1):

Если в гугле набрать file_get_contents , то первая ссылка будет вот сюда - 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

А первый пример вот этот -

```php
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
    echo $homepage;
?>
```

В вашем же примере вы загружаете данные файла... куда ?

Comment: Да, так работает, спасибо!
А реально сделать ('dir/dir/'.the_field('filename'))? (т.е. чтобы к пути просто прибавлялось имя файла)
У меня получается, что только ссылку показывает, но не содержимое. Только в вашем примере сразу с полным путем показывает содержимое.